# Status bar for Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, statusbar, firefox-quantum

### 1. Summary

I use many addon buttons in Firefox.

[image: Addon buttons]

I don't find, how I can add additional bar for these buttons in Firefox Quantum.

I need add new bar, not modify already existing Menu and Bookmarks bars.

---

### 2. Not helped

1. In previous Firefox versions I use [**Status-4-evar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/) plugin, but it not [**Quantum-compatible**](https://github.com/SparkyBluefang/S4E/issues/54).
2. I don't find Quantum-compatible in **https://addons.mozilla.org** site; for example, not compatible [**New Add-on Bar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-add-on-bar/) or [**The Addon Bar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-addon-bar/) plugins.
3. I don't find, how I can solve this problem, in Google, for example, [**similar question**](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7cz5ng/status_bar_for_firefox_57/).

---

### 3. Do not offer

Please, do not offer:

1. use another browser,
2. downgrade Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with [`userChrome.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css). I found this Github where there are a lot of customizations for Firefox available: https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx

One that stood out was [`addonbar_extra_bookmarks_toolbar_below_navbar_fx65.css`](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/blob/master/classic/css/toolbars/addonbar_extra_bookmarks_toolbar_below_navbar_fx65.css). If you add its code to your `userChrome.css` file, it will add another bar below the navigation bar.

```
/* create an empty space below navigation toolbar */
/* Firefox Quantum userChrome.css tweaks ************************************************/
/* Github: https://github.com/aris-t2/customcssforfx ************************************/
/****************************************************************************************/


#main-window:not([customizing="true"]) #nav-bar {
  padding-bottom: 26px !important;
}

/* reduce maximum width of location bar and search bar on navigation toolbar */
#main-window:not([customizing="true"]) #nav-bar :-moz-any(#urlbar-container, #urlbar, #search-container, #searchbar)  {
  min-width: 50px !important;
}

/* move bookmarks to empty space below navigation toolbar, if on navigation toolbar */
#main-window:not([customizing="true"]) #nav-bar #personal-bookmarks {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 1px !important;
  min-width: 0 !important;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}

/* reduce size of bookmarks 'more bookmarks' menu chevron and remove its background color on navigation toolbar */
#nav-bar #personal-bookmarks #PlacesChevron .toolbarbutton-icon {
  min-width: 0px !important;
  min-height: 0px !important;
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: unset !important;
  box-shadow: unset !important;
}

/* set minimum height for bookmarks, when on navigation toolbar */
#nav-bar #personal-bookmarks toolbarbutton.bookmark-item:not(.subviewbutton) {
  min-height: 24px !important;
}

/* adjustments */
#nav-bar #personal-bookmarks {
  min-width: 40px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: 50vw !important;
}
```

Now you will have to move the Bookmarks Toolbar Items into the navigation bar using Firefox's customize option. Then you can use the bar just for add-ons, just drag them down.
[image: Customize]

I only have one add-on on this browser so it's not a great test but I can test more once I get home.

[image: Add-ons]

Comment: ```about:config > toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets > true``` (from the GitHub link)

Also nice is https://www.jeffersonscher.com/gm/url-bar-tweaks.html